# Passenger + Nginx "Cannot find module 'phusion_passenger/line_reader'"

Tags: node.js, nginx, passenger

I'm trying to run a Nodejs App but it returns

> Cannot find module 'phusion_passenger/line_reader'

I'm not able to fix it, I have about a Month researching and nothing.

I see there's a reference to `line_reader.js` on `/usr/share/passenger/node/phusion_passenger` that is what the error is not finding.

Here's the complete error info.

```
module.js:557
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'phusion_passenger/line_reader'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at Module.require (/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80:25)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:121:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
```

Thanks in advance.